# Encoding problem while sending email using java mail API

Tags: java, email, encoding

I am sending email using java mail api in my application. The subject of email contains hyphen( - ) character. This works fine on windows machine. But once I deploy the application on linux machine, the recipients of email get emails with hyphen getting converted into question mark in the subject of emails.

This problem is occurring in Cent OS linux environment. This is working fine with windows and ubuntu linux environment.

Can somebody please suggest what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the hyphen character is actually the regular ASCII hyphen (0x2D)? If it's something that looks like a hyphen, but is actually a Unicode character from a different language set, you could easily see encoding problems across environments.

Comment: I think you are right. I printed this character's numeric value and found it to be decimal 8211. It's definitely not ASCII hyphen. I copied subject from formatted email sent to me to my IDE and I think that's how Unicode hyphen slipped in. I suppose manually typing the subject in code will solve the problem.